# Three.js - Dynamically "build/draw" TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to simulate 3D text being **drawn out** or **built** inside my scene. The idea is to take the final score from a game and display it dynamically at the end of the game. If you don't know what I mean, imagine somebody graffiti-ing/tagging some numbers on a wall. The numbers don't **pop** in like they would if you typed them, but are constructed by building up each number.

[Reference for graffiti-ing](https://media.giphy.com/media/Se8EI2Erzek9y/giphy.gif)

I'm pretty sure that I want to use `TextGeometry` for this but I have absolutely no idea how I would go about making it appear dynamically and there aren't really any examples of this.

My only thought would be to hide each vertex in the `TextGeometry` and then make each vertex visible with a delay in between but I have no idea if that is anywhere near the right way to do it.

I know that it's possible to animate a line being drawn, but I'm going to need to use `TextGeometry` as I am using a specific font.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w67tzfhx/) is a great example of what I want, but with text instead of a line.

I don't have any code for this as I have no idea where to start, thanks in advance for your suggestions, any links/references/code examples are appreciated!

Comment: You can do _something_. Show your code, please.

Comment: @WestLangley Fair point, was hoping for a pointer/suggestion in a direction to get started but I will try messing around with the idea I had and add it to the question in a bit