# Three.js - Generate line at centre of TextGeometry (Skeleton)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am generating 3D text using `TextGeometry` with the following code:

```
var geomText;
var matText;
var Text;
var scoreForText = 5;

function createText() {
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( '/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

    geomText = new THREE.TextGeometry( scoreForText, {
        font: font,
        size: 80,
        height: 5,
        curveSegments: 4,
        bevelEnabled: false,
    });

    matText = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000});
    Text = new THREE.Mesh( geomText, matText );

    scene.add(Text);

});

}
```

I want to generate a `Line` that runs through the centre of the text, creating a "skeleton" of the text.

For example, if the text was an "S" it would be something like the following image, but in 3D.

[image: Letter S]

**Just for context**, I want to then remove the `TextGeometry` and be left just with the Line / Path so that I can add objects along the line to essentially build the letter/number out of objects.

How would I go about creating the centre line of a 3D `TextGeometry`?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This question is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50275697/9267033) which outlines the general idea of what I'm trying to do. WestLangley said I should add some code so I figured asking a more specific question is probably better as I know exactly what I will do after I have the centre line of the object.